# Url.Host in HttpContext.Current.Request and Page.Request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following method:

```
    public static string GetHttpHost(System.Web.HttpRequest hr)
    {
        return "http://" + hr.Url.Host + ":" + hr.Url.Port.ToString() ;
    }
```

When I call this method with `GetHttpHost(this.Request)` and `GetHttpHost(HttpContext.Current.Request)`, it returns different results.

For example:

- My request page is http://192.168.1.103/mypage.aspx
- In mypage.aspx.cs, calling `GetHttpHost(this.Request)` returns `http://192.168.1.103:80`
- When rendering mypage.aspx, some biz logic is involved, so BLL.dll is loaded. In BLL.dll, calling `GetHttpHost(HttpContext.Current.Request)` returns `http://app133:80` (app133 is our web server's name)

I searched in Stack Overflow, all related questions tell me that HttpContext.Current.Request and Page.Request are same object.

So, can anyone tell me what happened in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not obvious from your question, but you're using ASP.NET WebForms and inheriting from the `Page` class? Could you re-word your question for clarity, emphasising the context. Discussing `this` is quite hard without knowing what it is.

Comment: this.Request and HttpContext.Current.Request should be same but initialization of the Url property might differ if you request Url from page or from context.

What happens if you allways request HttpContext.Current.Request.Url first (like 'Uri dummyUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url') but then uses the this.Request.Url ?

Comment: @ProgrammingHero,I re-word my question. Hope now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

No, `HttpContext.Current.Request` and `Page.Request` are not the same. Both are instances of the same class (HttpRequest) but those are different instances.

In each case, the private `HttpRequest` instance is created differently - I could not find the exact code creating it but keep in mind that `HttpContext.Current` is created only once, long before any Page.

It all boils down to the following code in HttpRequest class:

```
public Uri Url
{
    get
    {
        if (this._url == null && this._wr != null)
        {
            string text = this.QueryStringText;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                text = "?" + HttpUtility.CollapsePercentUFromStringInternal(text, this.QueryStringEncoding);
            }
            if (AppSettings.UseHostHeaderForRequestUrl)
            {
                string knownRequestHeader = this._wr.GetKnownRequestHeader(28);
                try
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(knownRequestHeader))
                    {
                        this._url = new Uri(string.Concat(new string[]
                        {
                            this._wr.GetProtocol(), 
                            "://", 
                            knownRequestHeader, 
                            this.Path, 
                            text
                        }));
                    }
                }
                catch (UriFormatException)
                {
                }
            }
            if (this._url == null)
            {
                string text2 = this._wr.GetServerName();
                if (text2.IndexOf(':') >= 0 && text2[0] != '[')
                {
                    text2 = "[" + text2 + "]";
                }
                this._url = new Uri(string.Concat(new string[]
                {
                    this._wr.GetProtocol(), 
                    "://", 
                    text2, 
                    ":", 
                    this._wr.GetLocalPortAsString(), 
                    this.Path, 
                    text
                }));
            }
        }
        return this._url;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it first tries to read known request header (`GetKnownRequestHeader` method in `System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest` base class) and only if it fails it will invoke `GetServerName` method which will return either IP address or server name depending where the web application is hosted.

Didn't find any official documentation or proof as to why exactly one returns IP and other the machine name, but the above can explain the difference.